# SHow Block with php via .phtml on home page only

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1, page-layouts, page

I  am using this code to display a block on my home page, I opted to add it via the `onecolumn.phtml` file because when I added it as a widget via the cms method it would not allow for correct placement and full width without messing a bunch of other related stuff up.

However now it displays on all static cms pages ie about us etc.

**Is there some kind of way to check and only display on home page ?**

heres my snippet

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('threeblock1')->toHtml(); ?>
```

farther down the page i use this one and it only shows up on home page?

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('brands')->toHtml(); ?>
```

heres the complete code

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper <?php echo $this->getLang().'-lang-class';?>">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('threeblock1')->toHtml(); ?>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="main">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>



                                <div class="col-main">
                                    <div class="padding-s">
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>

                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

                                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product-categories')->toHtml(); ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('brands')->toHtml(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the block only on the homepage you can replace your code with:

```
<?php if ($this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true))): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('threeblock1')->toHtml(); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```